# How do I sum only unique values ​in a column of repeating values ​in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, report

I made a summary table to simplify my question. I have two columns named "Month" and "Price". Prices are the same by month. I want to sum the unique values ​​in the "Price" column. So I want to reach 30 + 50 + 80 + 60 = 220. How should I write a measurement for this?

[image: 1]

Thank you!

I used nested SUM() and DISTINCT() formulas but no results.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, for example:

```
=
SUMX(
    VALUES( 'Table'[Month] ),
    CALCULATE(
        MIN( 'Table'[Price] )
    )
)
```